# Swift Decode JSON with mixed types and possible sub structures

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decodable

I have to decode a given JSON structure coming from an API in Swift 4.
The problem is that at some point in the tree I have at the same level different kind of datas and one of the type can have sub elements.

I've tried several JSONDecoder and Decodable techniques but so far I havn't find a solution.

Simplified JSON :

```
{
    "menuName": "Menu 1",
    "menuId": 1,
    "menuGroups": [
        {
            "type": "group",
            "name": "Group 1",
            "menuEntry": [
                {
                    "type": "group",
                    "name": "Sub Group 1.1",
                    "menuEntry": [
                        {
                            "type": "menuItem",
                            "productName": "Item 1",
                            "productPrice": "9.00"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "menuItem",
                            "productName": "Item 2",
                            "productPrice": "12.00"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "type": "menuItem",
                    "productName": "Item 3",
                    "productPrice": "9.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are the decodables I'm trying to use :

```
struct Menu: Decodable {
    let menuName: String
    let menuId: Int
    let categories: [MenuCategory]

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case menuName
        case menuId
        case categories = "menuGroups"
    }
}

struct MenuCategory: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let name: String
    let items: [CategoryItem]

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case type
        case name
        case items = "menuEntry"
    }


}

enum CategoryItem: Decodable {
    case group(MenuCategory)
    case menuItem(MenuItem)

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            let item = try container.decode(MenuCategory.self)
            self = .group(item)
            return
        } catch let err {
            print("error decoding category: \(err)")
        }

        do {
            let item = try container.decode(MenuItem.self)
            self = .menuItem(item)
            return
        } catch let err {
            print("error decoding item: \(err)")
        }
        try self.init(from: decoder)
    }
}

struct MenuItem: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let productName: String
    let productPrice: String

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case type = "type"
        case productName
        case productPrice
    }
}
```

I think that using :

```
let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
```

is wrong because the container shouldn't be a single value container, but I don't know what to choose / do from here...

Would anyone have an idea on that ?
How would you decode some JSON like in the example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this stuct

```
struct YourStruct: Codable {
    let menuName: String
    let menuID: Int
    let menuGroups: [MenuGroup]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case menuName
        case menuID = "menuId"
        case menuGroups
    }
}

struct MenuGroup: Codable {
    let type, name: String
    let menuEntry: [MenuGroupMenuEntry]
}

struct MenuGroupMenuEntry: Codable {
    let type: String
    let name: String?
    let menuEntry: [MenuEntryMenuEntry]?
    let productName, productPrice: String?
}

struct MenuEntryMenuEntry: Codable {
    let type, productName, productPrice: String
}
```

and in datatask after cheking that you dont have an error

```
if let data = data {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                guard let decodedJson = try? decoder.decode(YourStruct.self, from: data) else { completion(nil) ; return }

            }
```

hope this help

Comment: Thanks, this is actually working, on the test set at least, I'll try now on the full dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You're very, very close, and have done a good job designing your data structures. You just need to try to decode each possible option in `CategoryItem`.

```
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if let item = try? container.decode(MenuCategory.self) {
        self = .group(item)
    } else if let item = try? container.decode(MenuItem.self) {
        self = .menuItem(item)
    } else {
        throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                                                debugDescription: "Not a group or item"))
    }
}
```

This container is a single value container because at this point in the decoding, you're decoding just one thing, a group or an item. It's up to each of those single values to handle their subcomponents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Doing so I've a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line:

`if let item = try? container.decode(MenuCategory.self) { `

Comment: I can't reproduce that in a storyboard using the JSON you provided. You'll need to dig deeper into the stack trace. A crash like that often suggests perhaps an unrelated memory management error elsewhere in the code.

Comment: After playing a bit with some do / catch I can get the following error :
`error : keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "menuEntryGroups", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "menuEntry", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\"name\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `name` field at `menuEntryGroups/Index 0/menuEntry/Index 0` (which doesn't match the JSON you posted above). In any case, it's telling you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: After having a longer looks at the errors and comparing with the json it seems that it's not changing between the Group and Item types, so he's trying to get the "name" property on an element that has the "productName" instead.
I'll investigate more why it doesn't change between the two.
Thanks